# Advantage Database 9.1, Create Table with PK

Tags: advantage-database-server

```
create table WEBLOG
(
ORDERNO CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
USERNAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ACTION CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
NOTE MEMO,
UPDATEDATE DATE NOT NULL,
UPDATETIME TIME NOT NULL,
IP CHAR(15),
PK CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(PK)
)
```

the above query does not work, the error message say,

```
ERROR IN SCRIPT: poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 2215;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid create options:  
NOCPTRANS and nullable column type options are only valid with ADS_VFP table type. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 23 (line: 3 column: 1)
```

what's wrong with that query?

My Advantage Database version is 9.1.

anybody know, please advice me.

Thanks!

Comment: Change your SQL to `PK CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY` instead. I believe it's the extraneous `,` after the PK CHAR(36) NOT NULL` and the addition of the final line (which is syntactically invalid) that's causing it.

Comment: @Ken White I change to 'PK CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY', but still same error message.

Comment: What language are you working in? What AdsTableType have you set for your query?

Comment: @Ken White I'm using Advantage Database Architect program, and I want to set table Type as ADT but I don't know how to set Table type in query.

Comment: If you're using Arc32, you set the table type up when you create the connection (alias) for your database. (For an existing connection, right-click the connection in the `Connection Repository`, choose `Connection Properties`, set `TableType`. For a new connection, use `Connection` from the main menu, and either `New Connection Wizard` or `Create New Connection`.)

Comment: @Ken White Thank you I just checked the table type, it is ADT.

Comment: @Ken White Do you know what cause that error message? If I remove NOT NULL and primary key in the query then it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is caused by using the `NOT NULL`, which is only supported on the ADS_VFP (Visual FoxPro) table type.

The usualy way to handle `NOT NULL` with Advantage is to make the connection via an ADS Data Dictionary, and then use the `CONSTRAINT NOT NULL` syntax instead. It won't work on `free table` (tables not in a data dictionary) connection, however - trying to just change it to `CONSTRAINT NOT NULL` on a free table results in the error `The field-level or record-level constraint is invalid.  Field level constraints are not supported on free table.`

This is documented in the [ADS 9.1 help](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/Advantage.htm), specifically under [CREATE TABLE](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/create_table.htm):

> vfp-option ::= NULL | NOT NULL | NOCPTRANS
>
> These options apply to Visual FoxPro tables (ADS_VFP) and can be used with free tables and data dictionary tables. The NULL (and NOT NULL) option indicate whether the column will be able to physically hold a NULL value. This is different from a NOT NULL constraint. If a Visual FoxPro column is created without the NULL option, then an error will be generated if an attempt is made to store a NULL in that column. The NOCPTRANS option applies to Visual FoxPro character and memo field types. If this option is provided, the data will not be translated across codepages (ANSI/OEM conversions).

BTW, when you get syntax error in `ARC32`, and your SQL is structured like yours is, the cursor is on the line causing the error. In this case, the error was caused on the very first column definition (`ORDERNO CHAR(9) NOT NULL`). Changing that single column definition to remove the `NOT NULL` makes the error occur on the next line.